# Enabling Adsense Management API

Tags: adsense-api

When I try to enable the adsense management api from the developer console api manager I get

> "The API doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it"

Why am I unable to enable the API? I can enable any other API's but not Adsense.

[image: Error]

Comment: Solved it by blocking adblock.